# Superscripts and bold dots

Tags: bold, superscripts

If I type

```
$\boldsymbol{\ddot\xi}^{\,n}$
```

I get

[image: this]

whereas on removing `\boldsymbol` and `\,` I get

[image: this]

How do I get the superscript to appear like this also with `\boldsymbol`?

Answer (score 1):

You should load the `bm` package. Compare

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

$\boldsymbol{\ddot\xi}^{\,n}$

\end{document}
```

which gives

[image]

with

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm}

\begin{document}

$\boldsymbol{\ddot\xi}^{\,n}$

\end{document}
```

which gives

[image]

Comment: Doesn't OP ask, that only dots be bold? And I don't see (and also reproduce) differences between both pictures.

Comment: Thanks, but this looks like incompatible with the "accents" package, and even after removing the accents package the file does not get compiled (typesetting gets stuck without any error). Of course your example works fine, but I cannot figure out what happens in my case...

Comment: @Zarko Look at the position of superscript n.

Comment: @Francesco I'm afraid `accents` and `bm` don't go along. Do you really need `accents`?

Comment: Thanks; yes, as I said I removed `accents` but the file does not get compiled although I get no errors...

Comment: @Francesco Try making a minimal failing example and ask a new question.

Comment: @egreg, yes, I overlooked this.

Comment: Alright, I got it: FYI, I just had to replace every `\boldsymbol` in my source file by a `\bm`. It looks like there's a conflict between the `bm` package and the command `\boldsymbol`...